# Get the Color from Colors.xaml in MAUI with C#

Tags: c#, maui

I have a `ContentPage` in my `MAUI` application. In my model, I want to have the background color to display. In the `App.xaml` I added few colors, for example:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="Primary01">#eff3fc</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Primary02">#e0e8fa</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So, I wrote this function

```
public static Color ColorBackgroundLetter(char letter)
{
    Color rtn;

    var hasValue = Application.Current.Resources
                       .TryGetValue("Primary01", out object primaryColor);

    if (hasValue)
        rtn = (Color)primaryColor;
    else
        rtn = Color.FromHex("#173880");

    return rtn;
}
```

With this code, I see the error code `CA1416: Validate platform compatibility` and those alerts:

[image]

Finding the color is not working in any platform. Is there a way to get the right color from the code behind?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to put the `<Color x:Key="Primary01">#eff3fc</Color>` in the Colors.xaml or Styles.xaml file.

Second, you need to add the following code in the App.xaml.

```
   <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
   <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
```

Last, you can create a method to get the color by using the code below.

```
if (App.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("Primary01", out var colorvalue))
   var Primarycolor = (Color)colorvalue;
```

Comment: This is what I’ve done but it is not working

Comment: This might be something wrong with your project and do you try to rebuild it after clean the bin and obj files? If it still appears this issue, you would better to report it as an issue on the GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that I see from your picture (do not do that), is that it cares about MAC < 10, and IOS < 10.

If we check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms

We will see that < 10 does not concern us anyway.

Also, I do not get this warning. And I am 100% sure that I did nothing to suppress it.

Comment: I have the latest version of Mac and iOS. When the application runs, it can't find the color I expected