# Reading from Colors.xaml in Maui c#

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am working in Maui 7 and need to know the technique for reading a Color identified in the

/Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml.

```
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="Primary">#512BD4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Secondary">#DFD8F7</Color>
</ReourceDictironary>
```

I have tried the Old Xamarin way. like this:

```
     var assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        // Helpful code for getting the full embedded resource name
     string[] names = assm.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

names Did not Have my data.

1. i have tried accessing in Assembly.GetManifestNames()
2. read this unanswered identical question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76828781/get-the-color-from-colors-xaml-in-maui-with-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.First();
```

You get a dictionary with keys of type string (example "Primary") and values of type `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color`.